# how to same array value merge for laravel stacked bar chart in laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel-10

i have one array and getting 360_video array data like [0,0,1,3,0] this.

```
$givenData = [
    [
        'date' => '2024-01-06', 'label' => 'fanzone', 'value' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2024-01-07','label' => '360_video','value' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2024-01-07', 'label' => '360_video', 'value' => 3,
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2024-01-08', 'label' => 'museum', 'value' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2024-01-09', 'label' => 'ecommerce', 'value' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2024-01-10', 'label' => 'main_lobby', 'value' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2024-01-10', 'label' => '2d_video', 'value' => 1,
    ],
];
```

and i required to below array data format for the chart.

```
{
            "label":"fanzone", "data": [1,0,0,0,0]
        },
        {
            "label":"360_video","data": [0,0,1,3,0]
        },
        {
            "label":"museum", "data": [1,0,0,0,0]
        },
        {
            "label":"ecommerce", "data": [0,0,0,1,0]
        },
        {
            "label":"main_lobby", "data": [0,1,0,0,0]
        },
        {
            "label":"2d_video", "data": [0,0,0,0,1]
        },
```

Any one help me how to i create new array for laravel 10 controller
this code for chart js in laravel stacked bar chart
Thanks is advance